# Angular material - Cannot find name 'MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS as described [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) as following:

```
@NgModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {floatLabel: 'always'}}
      ]
    })
```

But I get the following error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS'.

This is my versions:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.0

@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1002.0

@angular-devkit/core            10.2.0

@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.0

@angular/cdk                    10.2.6

@angular/cli                    10.2.0

@angular/material               10.2.6

@schematics/angular             10.2.0
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: can you reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to import it too:

```
import {MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Then:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' } },
  ]
```

Check out [this live demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmmnxkmxlvr?file=src/main.ts) for more, look inside `main.ts` and you will see it is used.